# IE document compatibility in iFrame

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

I have a web application that is used in an iframe by a web portal (SAP enterprise portal). The portal responds with header **x-ua-compatible IE=EmulateIE7**. This messes up my application which uses AngularJS. I tried following in my application but it does not work. How can I tell IE to use standard mode with my application?

Note changing the portal is not an option at this time.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="Edge"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Note changing the portal is not an option at this time."?

the best option is use header 
 in the page with angular application 
othewise  you could use the Iview DocumentObjectModel this iview has the property to define with way you want this page gets rendered 
you could choose between 
 IE7Emulated 
standards with it's edge mode for IE